# Algorithm to find the logarithm of a number

Tags: algorithm, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find a binary logarithm very fast? (O(1) at best)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668248/how-to-find-a-binary-logarithm-very-fast-o1-at-best)

how does the log function work.
How the log of a with base b is calculated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Calculation

Comment: Possible [Duplicate 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169641/where-to-find-algorithms-for-standard-math-functions) and [Duplicate 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668248/how-to-find-a-binary-logarithm-very-fast-o1-at-best)

Comment: Get your hands dirty: http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_log.c

Comment: Maybe you will find something here too : http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many algorithms for doing this.  One of my favorites (WARNING: shameless plug) is [this one based on the Fibonacci numbers.](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=zeckendorf-logarithm)  The code contains a pretty elaborate comment that goes into how the math works.  Given a and a<sup>b</sup>, it runs in time O(lg b) and O(1) space.

Hope this helps!