# Calculate logarithm in Java

Tags: java

How would I calculate logarithm in Java? How would I extend it to calculate for a sequence? I am trying to find solution for following:-

**N** different apps have different user growth rates. At a given time **t**, measured in days, the number of users using an app is **g^t** .

After how many full days will we have 1 billion total users across the **N** apps?

**Example 1**

Input: N = 1,  growthRates = [1.5]

output = 52

**Example 2**

Input: N = 3, growthRates = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3]

output = 79

Comment: Have you considered `Math.log()` and friends? Hard to see how this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831150/logarithm-algorithm).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logarithm Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831150/logarithm-algorithm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Logarithm in Java**

1. To calculate a common logarithm in Java we can simply use the `Math.log10()` method:

```
System.out.println(Math.log10(100));
```

2. To calculate a natural logarithm in Java we use the Math.log() method:

```
System.out.println(Math.log(10));
```

3. To calculate a logarithm with custom base in Java (log<sub>b</sub>(n) = log<sub>e</sub>(n) / log<sub>e</sub>), we can do it by defining a method as below:

```
private static double customLog(double base, double logNumber) {
    return Math.log(logNumber) / Math.log(base);
}
```

a details about mathematic and Logarithm can [be found here](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/core-java-modules/core-java-lang-math)