# How to generate all de Bruijn sequences using de Bruijn graphs (in JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, combinatorics

I have [this code](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/27e145248b3baa2e6331d25b831241b8) which I put together for trying to generate all possible de Bruijn sequences, but not getting "expected" results. It uses (what I think are called) [de Bruijn graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_graph), with Eulerian cycles.

```js
const SIZE = 8

const vertices = getEveryBitPermutation(SIZE).reduce((m, x) => {
  m.set(x, new Array)
  return m
}, new Map)

for (let [v, edges] of vertices) {
  const l = rol(v, SIZE)//.toString(2).padStart(SIZE, 0)
  const r = ror(v, SIZE)//.toString(2).padStart(SIZE, 0)
  edges.push(l)
  edges.push(r)
}

for (let string of collectStrings(vertices)) {
  if (isDeBruijnSequence(string, SIZE))
    console.log(string, parseInt(string, 2).toString(16))
}

function *collectStrings(vertices) {
  const strings = {}
  const visited = new Uint32Array(2 ** SIZE)
  for (let [v] of vertices) {
    // zero
    for (let i = 0, n = visited.length; i < n; i++) {
      visited[i] = 0
    }
    const string = dfs(v, vertices, visited).join('')
    yield string
    strings[string] = true
  }
  return Object.keys(strings).sort()
}

function dfs(start, vertices, visited, results = []) {
  const stack = [start]

  while (stack.length) {
    const v = stack.shift()
    visited[v] = 1

    const targets = vertices.get(v)

    if (targets) {
      targets.forEach(target => {
        if (visited[target] != 1) {
          visited[target] = 1
          results.push(target.toString(2).padStart(SIZE, 0))
          stack.push(target)
        }
      })
    }
  }

  return results
}

function getEveryBitPermutation(size) {
  let start = 2 ** (size - 1)
  let end = 2 ** size - 1
  const set = new Uint32Array(end - start)
  let i = 0
  while (start < end) {
    set[i++] = start++
  }
  return set
}

function rol(n, size) {
  const bits = n.toString(2).padStart(size, 0).split('').reverse()
  const left = bits.pop()
  bits.unshift(left)
  const string = bits.reverse().join('')
  const number = parseInt(string, 2)
  return number
}

function ror(n, size) {
  const bits = n.toString(2).padStart(size, 0).split('').reverse()
  const right = bits.shift()
  bits.push(right)
  const string = bits.reverse().join('')
  const number = parseInt(string, 2)
  return number
}

function isDeBruijnSequence(string, spanSizeInBits) {
  let bits = string.split('').reverse()
  let i = 0
  const totalElementSize = 2 ** spanSizeInBits
  const chunksVisited = new Uint8ClampedArray(totalElementSize)
  while (i < bits.length) {
    const chunk = bits.slice(i, i + spanSizeInBits)
    if (chunk.length < spanSizeInBits) {
      const diff = bits.slice(0, spanSizeInBits - chunk.length)
      chunk.push(...diff)
    }
    const string = chunk.reverse().join('')
    const number = parseInt(string, 2)
    if (chunksVisited[number] == 1) {
      return false
    }
    chunksVisited[number] = 1
    i++
  }
  return true
}
```

First of all, there is a `SIZE` property. This tells how many bits there are throughout the program. In this case, 8. So it generates all permutations of 8 bits (vertices), and then rotates left and right to generate two outward edges on each vertex. This creates a basic graph. Then it does DFS on this graph to generate walks I guess, and then outputs a string starting from each vertex. There is a function `isDeBruijnSequence` which checks if it's a de Bruijn sequence as well.

I am only getting a small handful (5-20 depending on `SIZE`) out of the possible hundreds of strings generated that turn out to be de Bruijn sequences. I am also not sure if I should be doing something else to get this right.

One final thing I am not sure about is how I distinguish between `n`. In my case, taking 8 bits as an example, since there are two edges, this means every 8-bit vertex will result in a 16-bit result. At least that's what it seems like it's doing. So wondering how I can correct this to generate *all possible de Bruijn sequences*, for any `SIZE`?

[Another code revision](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/27e145248b3baa2e6331d25b831241b8/c72e3f6eed578b2cead9cd4f3b14de5a8f756596) and results seem to be getting slightly better.

[This talk/presentation](http://web.mnstate.edu/goytadam/talks/DBS.pdf) seems say you can generate all the de Bruijn sequences from a graph in some sort of way, but I have seen a few different ways of structuring the edges and such, so not sure what the "correct" approach is or if I have it somewhat right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, it has to be a **hamiltonian cycle** that is traversed.

```
// import findCycle from 'find-cycle/directed'
import hamiltonianCycle from 'javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/src/algorithms/graph/hamiltonian-cycle/hamiltonianCycle.js'
import Graph from 'javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/src/data-structures/graph/Graph.js'
import GraphVertex from 'javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/src/data-structures/graph/GraphVertex.js'
import GraphEdge from 'javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/src/data-structures/graph/GraphEdge.js'

const SIZE = 5

const vertices = getEveryBitPermutation(SIZE).reduce((m, x) => {
  m[x.toString(2).padStart(SIZE, 0)] = new Array
  return m
}, {})

Object.keys(vertices).forEach(v => {
  Object.keys(vertices).forEach(v2 => {
    if (v != v2 && isWired(v, v2)) {
      if (!vertices[v].includes(v2))
        vertices[v].push(v2)
    }
  })
})

function isWired(a, b) {
  let a_end = a.split('')
  a_end.shift()
  a_end = a_end.join('')
  let b_start = b.split('')
  b_start.pop()
  b_start = b_start.join('')
  return a_end === b_start
}

let i = 1
for (let string of collectStrings(vertices)) {
  // if (isDeBruijnSequence(string, SIZE))
    console.log(String(i++).padStart(4, ' '),
      isDeBruijnSequence(string, SIZE) ? '!' :' ',
      string,
      parseInt(string, 2).toString(16)
    )
}

function *collectStrings(vertices) {
  const visited = new Uint32Array(2 ** SIZE)
  let j = 0
  for (const v in vertices) {
    // zero
    for (let i = 0, n = visited.length; i < n; i++) {
      visited[i] = 0
    }
    const strings = dfs(j++, v, vertices, visited, 1)
    for (let string of strings) {
      if (string) yield string
    }
  }
}

function dfs(i, start, vertices, visited, dir, results = []) {
  const graph = new Graph(true)
  graph.addVertex(new GraphVertex(start))
  Object.keys(vertices).forEach(v => {
    const vertex = new GraphVertex(v)
    try {
      graph.addVertex(vertex)
    } catch (e) {}
  })
  Object.keys(vertices).forEach(v => {
    const vertex = graph.getVertexByKey(v)
    vertices[v].forEach(e => {
      graph.addEdge(new GraphEdge(vertex, graph.getVertexByKey(e)))
    })
    try {
      graph.addEdge(new GraphEdge(vertex, graph.getVertexByKey(start)))
    } catch (e) {}
  })
  const cycle = hamiltonianCycle(graph)

  while (cycle.length) {
    const vertexes = cycle.pop()
    const key = []
    vertexes.forEach(vert => {
      key.push(vert.value[vert.value.length - 1])
    })
    results.push(key.join(''))
  }

  return results
}

function getEveryBitPermutation(size) {
  let start = 0
  let end = 2 ** size
  const set = new Uint32Array(end - start)
  let i = 0
  while (start < end) {
    set[i++] = start++
  }
  return set
}

function isDeBruijnSequence(string, spanSizeInBits) {
  let bits = string.split('').reverse()
  let i = 0
  const totalElementSize = 2 ** spanSizeInBits
  const chunksVisited = new Uint8ClampedArray(totalElementSize)
  while (i < bits.length) {
    const chunk = bits.slice(i, i + spanSizeInBits)
    if (chunk.length < spanSizeInBits) {
      const diff = bits.slice(0, spanSizeInBits - chunk.length)
      chunk.push(...diff)
    }
    const string = chunk.reverse().join('')
    const number = parseInt(string, 2)
    if (chunksVisited[number] == 1) {
      return false
    }
    chunksVisited[number] = 1
    i++
  }
  return true
}
```

Sample output from the stream:

```
30698 ! 00100011001111101101001010111000 233ed2b8
30699 ! 00100011001111101010010110111000 233ea5b8
30700 ! 00100011001111101001010110111000 233e95b8
30701 ! 00100011001110110101001011111000 233b52f8
30702 ! 00100011001110110100101011111000 233b4af8
30703 ! 00100011001110101001011011111000 233a96f8
30704 ! 00100011001110100101011011111000 233a56f8
30705 ! 00100011001011111011010100111000 232fb538
30706 ! 00100011001011101101010011111000 232ed4f8
30707 ! 00100011001011011111010100111000 232df538
30708 ! 00100011001011011101010011111000 232dd4f8
```

It takes 1.5 minutes to generate all 65536 de Bruijn sequences for `n = 5`. For `n > 5` it crashes, using too much memory to generate all the hamiltonian cycles.

Comment: In fact, you need to search for eulerian cycles in the (n − 1)-dimensional de Bruijn graph. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence#Construction