# How to find the first non zero bit starting from msb

Tags: c

I have an array of 20 words/bytes storing a 160 bit number. How can I find the first nonzero bit starting from msb . I need to find the position of the bit and then accordingly from the first '1' position I need to do some operations.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i?rq=1) might be helpful

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find most significant bit (left-most) that is set in a bit array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589096/find-most-significant-bit-left-most-that-is-set-in-a-bit-array)

Answer (score 7):

If you're using gcc, there are builtin functions doing exactly that (and many other things)

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.4/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

The one you're looking for is probably `__builtin_clz` (for unsigned int), `__builtin_clzl` (for unsigned long) or `__builtin_clzll` for unsigned long long.

From the documentation:

> Returns the number of leading 0-bits in x, starting at the most significant bit position. If x is 0, the result is undefined

So go over your ints (longs? longlongs?) from the most significant until you find the first that isn't zero. Then use the appropriate `__builtin_clz` to find how many leading zeros it has, and 32 (64) minus that number is the location of the highest `1` bit in your number!

Of course you can always implement `__builtin_clz` for yourself if you want to be compatible with other compilers (as you should!)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate for each byte until you find the first that is != 0. For each byte that is equals to zero, increment a counter by 8.

Then with that byte, do a shift right operation (>> 1) until that value is equal to zero. In each shift, increment the previous counter by 1.