# For a binary vector, find the largest index with a value of 1

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, time-complexity, bitwise-operators, binary-search

Consider an arbitrary binary vector of dimension *n*. For *n*=4, an example vector might be 1100.

For such a vector, I'd like to know the top-most position whose bit has the value of 1. For the 1100 example above, I'd like to get the answer 4 (counting from the right).

A recursive O(log(*n*)) solution (more or less binary search) for the example case above is

1. Start with 1100
2. Split down the middle into two 2-bit vectors 11 and 00
3. Is the first of these greater than zero? Yes it is, so we focus now only on the first 2-bit vector (i.e. we know that our position answer can't be 1 or 2...it must be 3 or 4)
4. Split 11 into two 1-bit vectors 1 and 1
5. Is the first of these greater than zero? Yes, and it's also 1-bit long. We know that this is our position, so we return it.

My question: Assuming in a practical setting that 1) n is not greater than the word size on a general-purpse computer (i.e. *n*<=64), and 2) that we're given the "common" general-purpose instruction set, is there any way to do this in O(1) operations (worst case) with respect to the size of the vector instead of O(log(*n*))? I'm quietly hoping that there might be some combination of bitwise instructions that one could exploit, although my hopes are not high :(.

Note: using some kind of static structure which maps each possible vector to a result is not practical (would require too much memory for e.g. the *n*=64 case).

Comment: For a real computer, this would be a [dupe of this question, I guess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589096/find-most-significant-bit-left-most-that-is-set-in-a-bit-array). :)

Comment: Nice! I wasn't aware of BSF and BSR! Do these instructions actually execute in one clock cycle though (i.e. are they actually implemented in hardware or are they just a macro for a different technique)?

Comment: It varies (a lot, it seems) with the exact processor model.

Comment: Thanks! I guess if this is a duplicate it's not worth going through the entire answering process right? I'll just upvote your helpful comments and flag this as a dupe.

Comment: If you're also interested in more theoretical answers, there is an O(1) algorithm for this (but it includes multiplications) and a multiplication-free O(log log n) algorithm (for them, as in this question, it is assumed that n-bit operations take constant time). Both are covered in The Art of Computer Programming V4. Neither are, in practice, anywhere near as good as `bsr` or various other hardware specific tricks

Comment: Thanks for your comment and reference Harold :). Although the problem that motivated my question is more practical in nature, I'm always fascinated by the theoretical side too. I'll check it out :).