# Finding the smallest power of 2 greater than n

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I came across a piece of code for finding the smallest power of 2 greater than a 32-bit integer n...

```
n+=(n==0);
n--;
n|=n>>1;
n|=n>>2;
n|=n>>4;
n|=n>>8;
n|=n>>16;
n++;
```

Now how does it work? I tried printing the number in base-2 after every step for n=100, but it didn't make much sense. What's the logic behind it?

Comment: I thought this was for a 32bit integer?

Comment: It works only with 32-bit uint. BTW there was [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i): nextpow2 is same number if it is a power of two (`x & ( x – 1) == 0`) and its `msb << 1` otherwise.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes. Sorry, i edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This piece of code fills all the least significant bits of the given number `n` with binary `1`s and after that increases the result by `1`, achieving the requested outcome. E.g., for input `101` the bit manipulations will yield `111` and after the increase by `1` it will become `1000`(8), which is indeed the least power of 2 greater then `101`(5).

**Update**: Actually, this is an optimization to the trivial method of just setting each lsb bit manually. Why this optimization achieves the same result is a different question in a broader scope which is beyond this question.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it finds the smallest power of 2 greater or equal than `n` and it works for 32 bit unsigned numbers.

- The first line just treats 0 the same way as 1 (written in a somewhat confusing way)
- The second line accounts for the "or equal", if a number is exactly a power of two we make it one bit shorter.
- the next few lines make sure, that all lower bits are set to 1. First we shift right by 1 and do a logical or. The effect is that now the highest bit and the bit immediately below are set to 1. Doing the same now with a shift of 2 makes the top 4 bits one, and so on.
- finally we have a number that is one less than a power of two and we just add 1.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to icepack's answer: As explained [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2), the algorithm calculates `1 << (floor(log_2(n - 1)) + 1)`.