# Faster Log2Ceil

Tags: c#, math, bit-manipulation

I was wondering if somebody knows a faster way to implement the function below, a computation of  logarithm of 2 ceiling on integers, in C#.

```
private int Log2Ceil(int x)
{
   return (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log((double)x, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i). The code it references is in C, but most of it works in C# as well.

Alternatively, you can use

```
private int Log2Ceil(int n) {
    long bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits((double)n);
    return ((int)(bits >> 52) & 0x7ff) - 1022;
}
```

which uses the fact that floating-point numbers contain an encoding of the binary exponent. A quick benchmark showed this to be 13x faster than your original on x64 and about 21x faster on x86.

Answer (score 0):

I also found another way to do that, as described [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious).

```
private int Log2Ceil(int x)
{
    uint v = (uint)(x - 1); // 32-bit word to find the log base 2 of
    uint r = 0; // r will be lg(v)
    while (v > 0) // unroll for more speed...
    {
        v >>= 1;
        r++;
    }
    return (int)r;
}
```

Comment: This is the floor of a base-2 logarithm, not the ceil of it.