# Find out (in C++) if binary number is prefix of another

Tags: c++, c, binary, bit-manipulation, integer-arithmetic

I need a function with a header like this:

```
bool is_prefix(int a, int b, int* c) {
    // ...
}
```

If a is, read as a binary number string, a prefix of b, then set *c to be the rest of b (i.e. "what b has more than a") and return true. Otherwise, return false. Assume that binary strings always start with "1".

Of course - it is easy to do by comparing bit by bit (leftshift b until b==a). But is there a solution which is more efficient, without iterating over the bits?

Example: `a`=100 (4), `b`=1001 (9). Now set `*c` to 1.

Comment: Can you give a numeric example? Should the overlap be on the high or the low end of b?

Comment: Does the first bit of the prefix have to begin with `1`? Because unless the bits in `a` are in reverse order to those in `b`, I don't see how you'd be able to limit the bits in `a` to just the prefix as `a` and `b` are going to be the same size as integer values.

Comment: Shift the low-order bits of b off to the right until a and b are equal.

Comment: @HotLicks that's basically comparing bit by bit, except it makes `a` not being a prefix a worst-case scenario as `b` would have to be shifted and compared `sizeof(int)*8` times before you could be sure `a` wasn't the prefix.

Comment: @JAB - No, it's comparing a max of N times for an N-bit-wide value.

Comment: How does your easy solution work?

Comment: @Pixelchemist I added an example.

Comment: @JAB yes, consider a and b as beginning with 1.

Comment: @JAB - You can, of course, "short-circuit" things a bit by testing for zero leading bytes in the arguments and by giving up when b has become smaller than a.  But the basic algorithm is sound, and reasonably fast.

Comment: @n.m. Basically, get log2 of both numbers, then position readers on the first bits of both, then move both readers forward bit by bit.

Comment: Note that taking the log2 or some such will be slower than iterating over bits in most cases.

Comment: @HotLicks A more consistent case would be shifting up such that the first bits of both `a` and `b` are 1 (could be determined using a basic numeric calculation if I'm not mistaken, but then again maybe I am, but that in itself could possibly be obviated by using a reference array/etc.), then checking if `a` is able to mask the number of upper bits of `b` equal to `sizeof(int) * 8 - ashift`), and if so take that masked value of `b` and shift it down back to normal and store in `c`.

Comment: That's a hard solution. An easy solution would be to find such a number N that a>>N==b. Iff such N exists, b is a prefix of a. You can use binary search if linear search over bits-per-your-integral-type is too slow.

Comment: @n.m. Binary search seems to be a useful idea!

Comment: @JAB - There are a half-dozen different strategies for short-circuiting, but they all risk being more expensive than a straight-forward solution.

Comment: It may or may not give you a performance increase (my bet is on "not" but that's just a guess).

Comment: Looping over a maximum of 64 (or 32) bits is very unlikely to be any kind of performance issue. You should aim for portability and readability instead.

Comment: @oseiskar Depends on how often the function will be used, really. If it's called repeatedly, using a basic optimization to reduce the calculation time is probably not a bad idea (assuming the compiler wouldn't be doing it in the first place, which could be a possibility). Going by http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogLookup, it seems using a lookup table would be more efficient than down-shifting `b` when `a` is small and `b` is large, though Johannes' example utilizes a small `b`.

Comment: (And a case with `b` and `a` both large but being only a few bits different in length would similarly have potential to be quicker than the lookup table.)

Comment: Someone once said something about "premature optimization".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your favorite ["fast" method to find the highest set bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/671815/315052). Let's call the function `msb()`.

```
bool is_prefix (int a, int b, int *c) {
    if (a == 0 || b == 0 || c == 0) return false;
    int d = msb(b) - msb(a);
    if (d < 0) return false;
    if ((b >> d) == a) {
        *c = b ^ (a << d);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Shift `b` so its high order bit aligns with `a`, and compare that with `a`. If they are equal, then `a` is a "prefix" of `b`.

This algorithm's performance depends on the performance of `msb()`. If it is constant, then this algorithm is constant. If `msb()` is expensive, then the "easy approach" may be the fastest approach.

Comment: Did you assume that the first bits of `a` and `b` are at the same position, so if a is shorter, it is right-padded with zeros?

Comment: Infinite loop if `a` = 0. Edit: fixed now

Comment: @kotlomoy: It depends on `msb()`, but I'll disallow `0` input.

Comment: If `msb(a) > msb(b)` then `d` is negative and the expression `b >> d` results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @jxh: Reducing to a common problem is always a good idea. Thanks!

Comment: @jxh: Why do we check for `b!=0`? The case `a=b=0` should be legal, and the algorithm returns false for it.

Comment: @Johannes: Adjust the function as you see fit. I just wanted to avoid calling `msb()` on input that might not have a sensible return value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure, but would something like the following work:

```
bool
is_prefix( unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned* c )
{
    unsigned mask = -1;
    while ( mask != 0 && a != (b & mask) ) {
        a <<= 1;
        mask <<= 1;
    }
    c = b & ~mask;
    return mask != 0;
}
```

(Just off the top of my head, so there could be errors.)

Comment: This looks like bit-by-bit? (similar to my "easy approach")