# how to find how many bits exist in a int number and storing each bit in an int array

Tags: c

I have something like `int i=10` it could be `i=1000` or `i=10400233`

I like to store each bit from any number stored in  `int i=10//,etc.` in an array. Is it possible in `C`

I just don't get it how can we find the relationship between `bits` and `int` variable with a number stored in it

example inputs

> int i=10; // I want int array[]={1,0,1,0};

> int i=15; // I want int array[] ={1,1,1,1};

> int i=21 // I want int array[] ={1,0,1,0,1};

Comment: Bits with value `0` are bits too, so all `int` will have the same number of bits (in a given compiled binary).

Comment: Can you please rephrase and/or clarify the question as it is not clear. Perhaps give the result of some example inputs. But in general to extract bit X would be `(i >> X) & 1`

Comment: @JoachimSauer do u mean its simply not possible because there is no way of finding how many bits represent a number. what if I tell on my system `printf("%d\n",sizeof(int));` prints `4`

Comment: I think the first comment is saying that the number of bits for every `int` value is the same. It is `sizeof(int)*8`.

Comment: @kaylum I have updated my question with test inputs

Comment: So you want all significant bits avoiding leading zeroes?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I want bits that can represent a decimal number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find most significant set bit in a long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939998/find-most-significant-set-bit-in-a-long)

Comment: So you have multiple questions in this post. That duplicate shows how to find the most significant bit. You can then use bit shift and mask to get each bit starting from the most significant to the 0-th bit. Give it a try and come back to show your code if you have any specific difficulty.

Comment: Kaylum gave you a way to extract a bit from an `int`, and to obtain the number of bits in an `int`. That is sufficient. Try to write some code, now.

Comment: what I can say it I need some upper bound on number of bits. If my int is 4 byte long than it worth trying 32 bits and do `int j=i>>31 & 0b1;` and `int j=i>>30 & 0b1;` and `int j=i>>29 & 0b1;`,.....`int j=i>>1 & 0b1;`

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès can u please look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

> I just don't get it how can we find the relationship between bits and int variable with a number stored in it

First it's important to understand that the number of bits used to store an `int` is a fixed number on the specific system being used. Different systems may use a different number of bits.

**BUT** ... The number of bits **doesn't** depend on the value held by the `int`. The number of bits used to store an `int` is a system-specific constant.

You can fid the number of bits like:

```
printf("int is %zu chars and each char is %d bits so in total %zu bits\n", 
       sizeof(int),              // Chars per int
       CHAR_BIT,                 // Bits per char
       sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT);  // Bits per int
```

On my system I get:

```
int is 4 chars and each char is 8 bits so in total 32 bits
```

Once you have calculated the number of bits, you can create an array of that size. Either a VLA (variable length array) or a dynamic allocated array (i.e. using `malloc`).

Answer (score 0):

This is how its done when sizeof(int) is 4 on my system

```
   #define CHAR_BIT_C 8
    
    int main()
    {
        int i=21;
        
        int t[32];
    
        for(int x=CHAR_BIT_C*sizeof(int)-1;x>=0;x--)
        {
            *(t+x)=i>>x&0b1;
        }
        for(int x=CHAR_BIT_C*sizeof(int)-1;x>=0;x--){
            printf("%d ",*(t+x));
        }

        return 0;        
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have the variable `j`? -- Please raise the warning level of your compiler to the maximum and handle all warnings and errors. -- Use some blanks to make your source more readable. -- `void main()` is not one of the standard compliant main functions.

Comment: @thebusybee how to raise the warning level of gcc compiler to the maximum? And how to remove it

Comment: Well, your first stop should always be the documentation. It is available by a simple web search and in different formats, even in PDF. Additional tutorials are widespread. -- Anyway, use at least `-Wall -Wextra` as options to the compile command line. Depending on your IDE and the type of project there might be a dialog for this.