# Determining Exponent of Power of Two Integer?

Tags: c++, int

Is there any way other than `log_2(x)` for determining which power an integer is ? Knowing of course that it is a power of two, (binary base `0001`, `0010`, `0100`, `1000`, etc...).
Mostly I don't want it to convert to a floating point number and I don't want it to simple use an array search.

Comment: C or C++? Pick one...

Comment: Well if there's a better way with templates it doesn't matter, though that'd only work if it was a compile time constant.

Comment: @skln C and C++ are two different languages.

Comment: You can use the bitshift operators (`<<`,`>>`) and test with the boolean AND operator (`&`).

Comment: Indeed but they share a lot of similarities, mostly how integers are stored and all the operators that can be performed on them. If you can give me a C solution that can't some how be directly translated into C++ I shall remove one or the other.

Comment: Any solution with a variable named `new` or `class` will satisfy this criteria.

Comment: @skln Bitshifting works the same way for c or c++. I recommend to use unsigned type to store the values you want to test!

Comment: @skln: You should tag the question with the language that you're actually using.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I said C to C++, not the other way around. Even so, are you telling me you can't allocate memory in C ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Looping through the bits also isn't ideal but if there is no other "trick" or solution I guess it will have to do.

Comment: @skln, `new` and `class` are not keywords in C, so you can name a variable `new` in C, but if you were to attempt to compile it in C++ it would return a compile error.  That's what Paul Griffith's statement meant.

Comment: Removed the [C] tag, that last comment clearly indicated that you are not using C, but C++ :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I don't understand what made you choose `C++` over `C`. What exactly was the indicator for this question to be for `C++` rather than `C`?

Comment: Isn't that the same as finding the most significant bit? Then the question is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i

Comment: This is the well known "find first set" problem.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: The answer to `new` and `delete` from someone doing C would not be *are you telling me you can't allocate memory in C*? Yes, you can, just not with `new` and `delete`, everyone doing `C` knows that :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas He was :) just :) being sarcastic :) I think... ... :) Like in *"Are you telling me you can't allocate memory in C? If so, then you seriously are missing some valuable knowledge about C."* The question wasn't C not C++ specific, I think it should rather remain like that, but whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is **count the trailing zeroes** of a number, although **counting the leading zeroes** and subtracting from 32 or 64 can work just as well when the number is a power of two. [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightLinear) provides many ways to do this.

**Count the consecutive zero bits (trailing) on the right linearly**

```
unsigned int v;  // input to count trailing zero bits
int c;  // output: c will count v's trailing zero bits,
        // so if v is 1101000 (base 2), then c will be 3
if (v)
{
  v = (v ^ (v - 1)) >> 1;  // Set v's trailing 0s to 1s and zero rest
  for (c = 0; v; c++)
  {
    v >>= 1;
  }
}
else
{
  c = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(v);
}
```

**Count the consecutive zero bits (trailing) on the right in parallel**

```
unsigned int v;      // 32-bit word input to count zero bits on right
unsigned int c = 32; // c will be the number of zero bits on the right
v &= -signed(v);
if (v) c--;
if (v & 0x0000FFFF) c -= 16;
if (v & 0x00FF00FF) c -= 8;
if (v & 0x0F0F0F0F) c -= 4;
if (v & 0x33333333) c -= 2;
if (v & 0x55555555) c -= 1;
```

**Count the consecutive zero bits (trailing) on the right by binary search**

```
unsigned int v;     // 32-bit word input to count zero bits on right
unsigned int c;     // c will be the number of zero bits on the right,
                    // so if v is 1101000 (base 2), then c will be 3
// NOTE: if 0 == v, then c = 31.
if (v & 0x1) 
{
  // special case for odd v (assumed to happen half of the time)
  c = 0;
}
else
{
  c = 1;
  if ((v & 0xffff) == 0) 
  {  
    v >>= 16;  
    c += 16;
  }
  if ((v & 0xff) == 0) 
  {  
    v >>= 8;  
    c += 8;
  }
  if ((v & 0xf) == 0) 
  {  
    v >>= 4;
    c += 4;
  }
  if ((v & 0x3) == 0) 
  {  
    v >>= 2;
    c += 2;
  }
  c -= v & 0x1;
}
```

And three more examples which use floats and array lookups, which you've specified you do not want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Several ways to do it. One on top of my head, you can divide it by 2, until it is `1`:

```
int logbase2( unsigned int n ) {
    int exp = 0;
    if ( n == 0 )
        return -1;
    while ( n != 1 ) {
        n /= 2;
        exp++;
    }
    return exp;
}
```

And `logbase2( yournumber );` shall yield the result you want. More generally, it shall yield the integer part of the actual logarithm on base 2 of the number `yournumber`.

Comment: Try the number 5, which is not a power of 2.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Exactly, 5 is not a power of 2, which means that it is not my/our concern, since *skln* guaranteed us that we will only be dealing with numbers that are powers of 2 in his/her question. When you pass `5` as the parameter to my function, you'll get the result `2`, which, as I said, is the integer part of the [`log_2( 5 ) = 2.321928`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log+base+2+5) in maths.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bit comparison test based on iterating with a bit shift operation:

```
unsigned int power_of_2(unsigned int x) {
    // Note that *8 hardcoded isn't ideal here. There's a constant available that
    // specifies the 'byte' size (bitwise) for the actual architecture. 
    // But this is really depending on your C or C++ compiler.
    for(size_t p2 = 0; p2 < sizeof(x)*8; ++p2) { 
        if(x & (1 << p2)) {
            return p2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The following calls give you the output shown below:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << power_of_2(0x0080) << " "
              << power_of_2(0x0040) << " "
              << power_of_2(0x0020) << " "
              << power_of_2(0x0010) << " "
              << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Output:

```
7 6 5 4
```

Check a live sample [here](http://ideone.com/1JNFAY) please.