# Javascript: Testing for perfect squares without using the inbuilt squareroot formula

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and taking some tests on codewars, I am writing a code that checks for perfect numbers i.e. if a number has a squareroot that is a whole number it should return true. Here is my code and it only works for 0 and 1, from here it returns false even for numbers that are perfect squares. I need to understand why my code is not working and i cannot see where my problem is.

```
var isSquare = function(n){
      for ( var i=0; i>=0; i++){

      var product= i*i;
      if( product === n ) 
      return true;

      else if(product !==n)
      return false;

      }
    }
```

Comment: have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35855948/2417602)

Comment: Thanks so much, I have gone through it, Really helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `return false` is running *every time* the input `n` is not equal to the tested `product`. That is, on the first iteration, it will `return false` if `n` is not `0`. You should probably only `return false` if `n` is *smaller* than the tested `product`, and leave out the iteration condition because the test is being done in the loop body:

```js
var isSquare = function(n) {
  for (var i = 0;; i++) {
    var product = i * i;
    if (product === n) return true;
    else if (product > n) return false;
  }
}
console.log(isSquare(9));
console.log(isSquare(10));
```

Comment: you don't need else if you can move it outside loop since if it is not returning true it will return false

Comment: I don't think so, because otherwise, what would determine when the loop terminates? I know *usually* you can do that, but this isn't one of those cases unless one wanted to re-write much of the code

Comment: i forgot that you didn't put an expression, if you did then it will terminate when the loop is end

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out where my issue is, your code worked and i have understood where my problem is;)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with else if since you don't need else if, move the return outside the loop, it will keep checking until your loop get false, and you need also to rewrite your boolean expression

```js
 var isSquare = function(n){
          for ( var i=0; i<n; i++){
    
          var product= i*i;
          if( product === n ) 
          return true;
          }
         return false;
        }
        console.log(isSquare(9))
        console.log(isSquare(4))
        console.log(isSquare(12))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your code worked and i have understood where my problem is;)

Comment: Remeber to vote up accept answer if it is really help you

Comment: I would have loved to but my reputation is less than 15 so I cannot upvote answers at the moment. I will when I get to that level though

Comment: actually @CertainPerformance's answer has more performance, since my loop stop until i reach n while his loop will stop until i*i reach n
so my loop will stop after 1000 iteration while his loop will stop after 10 iterations