# for loop doesn't render in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, debugging, visual-studio-code

I think my solution is right I mean algorithm but this isn't rendered by node.js my console just stop (My Goal: want to calculate positive whole numbers root square without using javascript own functions)

---

THIS IS MY CODE:

```
   function squareRoot(number){
 
    if(number<0 ||  false === Number.isInteger(number)){
      return 'PLEASE ENTER POSITVE WHOLE NUMBER!!!'
    }else{
        let container=0;
        for(let root=0; container<number;root=root+0.1 ){
          if(number===root*root){
            return root;
          }else{}
             }
         }
         };
      console.log(squareRoot(9));
```

Comment: [Improving algorithm for finding square roots of perfect squares without Math.sqrt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35855799/javascript-improving-algorithm-for-finding-square-roots-of-perfect-squares-wit)

Comment: Floating point numbers don't work like you would normally expect. This isn't a "Javascript" thing, this is true EVERY programming language that uses floating point.  While I did vote to close this question, the linked answer goes into a lot of detail.