# Why k*k <= n is better than k <= Math.sqrt(n)

Tags: algorithm

I was researching algorithm of finding primal numbers and saw the statement below, I don't get why.

```
while (k*k <= n)
```

is better than

```
while (k <= Math.sqrt(n))
```

Is it because of function call? That calling function uses more resources.

Update: As @Codor said I think I need to mention that `k` is changed inside loop, while `n`is not changed.

So if I store `Math.sqrt(n)` before and use it every time, will it be more efficient than multiplying each time `k*k`?

Comment: simple multiplication of `k*k` will be much faster than calculating square-root of a number.

Comment: Which language is this? C#?

Comment: @Codor this is C# but I believe, it doesn't make much difference?

Comment: "So if I store Math.sqrt(n) before and use it every time, will it be more efficient than multiplying each time k*k?" 
Yes, Definitely. One is calling the whole function while other is just accessing a variable.

Comment: @Hatik I am using `2^(m/2)` where `2^m<=n` instead of `sqrt(n)` see [Prime numbers by Eratosthenes quicker sequential than concurrently?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22477240/2521214) if you store `sqrt` before loop than sqrt should be faster but that depends on the `n` architecture and other stuff too so it also might not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the call to `Math.sqrt` uses floating-point math, which might be more costly than the integer math used in the multiplication. On the other hand, `Math.sqrt` needs only one evaluation for the loop, while the evaluation of `k*k` needs several evaluations.

Comment: looking at `IL` `Math.Sqrt` is called over every iteration as well

Comment: I do not code in JAVA at all but does not JAVA use floats for everything (even for integers)? Or it was different language I mistaken this for... but yes sqrt is much more expensive than multiplication unless advanced and or **Quake3 style magic** approaches are used. For example if this [How to get a square root for 32 bit input in one clock cycle only?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34657972/2521214) is hardcoded into silicon could beat many things as it does not need even multiply ...

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot What is meant is that it is sufficient to evaluate sqrt(n) once, not that it is actually the case...

Answer (score 2):

Let us look at their time complexity for iterations:

- i=2 .. i*iO(sqrt(n))
- i=2 .. sqrt(n) `O(sqrt(n)*log(n))`
- i=2 .. sqrt (by Newton's method) `O(sqrt(n)) + O(log(n))`
- i=2 .. sqrt (by Math.sqrt) `O(sqrt(n))`

But as you edited, the pre-computed square root is more efficient than the multiplication that must be done each time around the loop.