# How to efficiently compute floor log base 2^(1/4)

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, numerical-methods

Computing `floor(log_2(x))` can be done by counting the number of zeros for which there are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i) fast algorithms.

Are there any similar tricks for computing `floor(log_{2^(1/4)}(x))` when `x` is an 64 bit unsigned int ranging over all possible values?

Since `log_{2^(1/4)}(x)=4*log_2(x)=log_2(x^4)`, this would be equivalent to finding an efficient algorithm for `floor(4*log_2(x))` or `floor(log(x^4))`.

Comment: log_{2^(1/4)}(x) = log_2(x)/log_2(2^(1/4)) = log_2(x)/(1/4) = 4 log_2(x)

Comment: Oh whoops, I forgot the 2^ in the denominator. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After we compute `floor(log_2(x))`, we can divide `z = x / 2^floor(log_2(x))` and consider the problem of computing `floor(log_{2^(1/4)}(z))` where `z` belongs to the range `[1, 2)`, since `floor(log_{2^(1/4)}(x)) = 4 floor(log_2(x)) + floor(log_{2^(1/4)}(z))`. There are only four possibilities for `floor(log_{2^(1/4)}(z))`, so two comparisons (three for branchless) of `z` with the constants

```
(2^(1/4))^1, (2^(1/4))^2, (2^(1/4))^3
```

will suffice. To avoid floating-point arithmetic entirely, the "divide" can be implemented as a left shift that leaves `(2^63) z` to be compared with similarly represented constants.

Now with C code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int mylog(unsigned long long x) {
  assert(x > 0ULL);
  /* compute n = floor(log2(x)) */
  unsigned long long y = x | (x >> 1);
  y |= y >>  2;
  y |= y >>  4;
  y |= y >>  8;
  y |= y >> 16;
  y |= y >> 32;
  y -= (y >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555ULL;
  y = (y & 0x3333333333333333ULL) + ((y >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333ULL);
  y = (y + (y >>  4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fULL;
  y = (y + (y >>  8)) & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffULL;
  y = (y + (y >> 16)) & 0x0000ffff0000ffffULL;
  y = (y + (y >> 32)) & 0x00000000ffffffffULL;
  int n = (int)y - 1;
  /* normalize x and use binary search to find the last two bits of the log */
  x <<= 63 - n;
  n <<= 2;
  if (x < 0xb504f333f9de6485ULL) {
    return x < 0x9837f0518db8a970ULL ? n     : n + 1;
  } else {
    return x < 0xd744fccad69d6af5ULL ? n + 2 : n + 3;
  }
}

int main(void) {
  unsigned long long x;
  while (scanf("%llu", &x) == 1) {
    printf("%d\n", mylog(x));
  }
}
```

The Mathematica/Wolfram Alpha query to compute the constants is

```
BaseForm[Table[Ceiling[2^(63+i/4)],{i,1,3}],16] .
```

Comment: That is magical, thanks!  As an added bonus, this is actually _more_ accurate than the naive `floor(4*log_2(x))` method due to rounding errors for large `x`.

Performance wise, a straightforward translation into Go doesn't produce as big a performance difference as I expected.  For random, uniformly distributed uint64 values, I am benchmarking `54.7ns/op` for the naive approach and `19.8ns/op` for the above.  The `log_2` calculation portion alone benchmarks at `7.9ns/op`.