# Compare and Identify the location and value at particular position and print it

Tags: c#, c, bit-manipulation, binary-data

I got stuck in solving the problem as shown below

Suppose I have two Variable A=10010101 [Correct Bit Value] & B=11001010 [Error Bit value which needs to be compared with A]

The above two variables are eight bit, I need to compare the value at each position from most significant bit to the last bit. What I need is to print the position where they are not identical and what should be the correct/error value for that position.

Example: For B, second position bit value should be '0' when we compared to bit value at position 2nd for A.

I tried to use XOR operation but in that case i didn't find the correct value at that position. Also i want to let you know that Bit A value is fixed and bit B value comes dynamically form a device.

Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: This lacks code, it's very much a "please write this for me" question.

Comment: @unwind sir no need to write if you can just help me with the logic.As I'm unable to code it of my own without proper logic. Thanks for review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compare bits and if they are different, print the index and corresponding bit from A.

```
for(i=0 to sizeof(A))
{
    tempA = A & (1 << i); //Get ith bit of A
    tempB = B & (1 << i); //Get ith bit of B
    if(tempA != tempB ) //Check if they are same.
        printf(i, tempA); //If they are different, print position and correct value.
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir for logic I'll code it and give u my feedback

Comment: If you do A XOR B you get an integer that only has bits set that are different in A and B. Then you can [search for highest bit set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i).

Comment: @Gerhardh: You are right. But I was just trying to explain the logic with some pseudo code. Also please note, you need to print all bits where error is occured, not just the highest bit.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, your logic should be like this:

```
ForEach elem in A 
    C[elem.index] = A XOR B

ForEach elem in C
    if elem == 1 
        print elem.index
```

Comment: Thanks sir for logic I'll code it and give u my feedback