# Is there an elegant and fast way to test for the 1-bits in an integer to be in a contiguous region?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I need to test whether the positions (from 0 to 31 for a 32bit integer) with bit value 1 form a contiguous region. For example:

```
00111111000000000000000000000000      is contiguous
00111111000000000000000011000000      is not contiguous
```

I want this test, i.e. some function `has_contiguous_one_bits(int)`, to be portable.

One obvious way is to loop over positions to find the first set bit, then the first non-set bit and check for any more set bits.

I wonder whether there exists a faster way? If there are fast methods to find the highest and lowest set bits (but from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i) it appears there aren't any portable ones), then a possible implementation is

```
bool has_contiguous_one_bits(int val)
{
    auto h = highest_set_bit(val);
    auto l = lowest_set_bit(val);
    return val == (((1 << (h-l+1))-1)<<l);
}
```

Just for fun, here are the first 100 integers with contiguous bits:

```
0 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 12 14 15 16 24 28 30 31 32 48 56 60 62 63 64 96 112 120 124 126 127 128 192 224 240 248 252 254 255 256 384 448 480 496 504 508 510 511 512 768 896 960 992 1008 1016 1020 1022 1023 1024 1536 1792 1920 1984 2016 2032 2040 2044 2046 2047 2048 3072 3584 3840 3968 4032 4064 4080 4088 4092 4094 4095 4096 6144 7168 7680 7936 8064 8128 8160 8176 8184 8188 8190 8191 8192 12288 14336 15360 15872 16128 16256 16320
```

they are (of course) of the form `(1<<m)*(1<<n-1)` with non-negative `m` and `n`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i

Comment: processor (eg dsp) might have specific instruction for bit checking (for non nul bit,...) but those are not portable.

Comment: Could you define `compact`? In particular, is `0x0` considered compact?

Comment: @aafulei yes, `0x0` is compact. It's easier to define the opposite (not compact): if there are wo set bits such there is at least one unset bit between them.

Comment: @KamilCuk `h>=l` by the (implied) functionality of `highest_set_bit()` and `lowest_set_bit()`

Comment: [OEIS A023758](https://oeis.org/A023758)

Comment: See e.g. this question [What is the fastest/most efficient way to find the highest set bit (msb) in an integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/671815/733637) (MSB). Then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/109025/733637) to the question [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109023/733637) (Nbits). Once you have MSB and Nbits, just build a value from them and verify it equals your input value..

Comment: That OEIS link says these numbers have their digits non-increasing when in binary.  Another way to refer to them would be to say that the ones are contiguous (or maybe connected).  To this mathematician, "compact" means something very different.

Comment: @Teepeemm I think one reason this question ended up on hot network questions is exactly because of this misuse of the word compact, it's certainly why I clicked on it: I wasn't thinking a lot and wondered how it could make sense to define compactness that way. Obviously it doesn't make sense.

Comment: How should the algorithm handle negative integers?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

##### Solution:

```
static _Bool IsCompact(unsigned x)
{
    return (x & x + (x & -x)) == 0;
}
```

##### Briefly:

`x & -x` gives the lowest bit set in `x` (or zero if `x` is zero).

`x + (x & -x)` converts the lowest string of consecutive 1s to a single 1 higher up (or wraps to zero).

`x & x + (x & -x)` clears that lowest string of consecutive 1s.

`(x & x + (x & -x)) == 0` tests whether any other 1 bits remain.

##### Longer:

`-x` equals `~x+1` (for the `int` in the question, we assume two’s complement, but `unsigned` is preferable). After the bits are flipped in `~x`, adding 1 carries so that it flips back the low 1 bits in `~x` and the first 0 bit but then stops. Thus, the low bits of `-x` up to and including its first 1 are the same as the low bits of `x`, but all higher bits are flipped. (Example: `~10011100` gives `01100011`, and adding 1 gives `01100100`, so the low `100` are the same, but the high `10011` are flipped to `01100`.) Then `x & -x` gives us the only bit that is 1 in both, which is that lowest 1 bit (`00000100`). (If `x` is zero, `x & -x` is zero.)

Adding this to `x` causes a carry through all the consecutive 1s, changing them to 0s.  It will leave a 1 at the next higher 0 bit (or carry through the high end, leaving a wrapped total of zero) (`10100000`).

When this is ANDed with `x`, there are 0s in the places where the 1s were changed to 0s (and also where the carry changed a 0 to a 1). So the result is not zero only if there is another 1 bit higher up.

Comment: At least somebody knows the book Hacker's Delight. Please see chapter 2-1 for the answer. But this has alread also been answered several times here on SO. Anyway: +1

Comment: That's an interesting property of the two's complement, and it's easy to see why it has to be so. Because multiplication is left shift. So that is to say,  `10011100`  is four times `100111`. Therefore, the two's complement of `10011100` has to be four times the two's complement of `100111`. But multiplication by four under two's complement is just a left shift that brings in two zeros, whether the value is negative or not. So we know the two's complement of `10011100` has to have those two zeros also.

Comment: I hope if you ever write such code in production, you include the explanation in comments ;)

Comment: This benefits nicely from x86 BMI1 to do `x & -x` in a single [`blsi`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blsi) instruction, which is 1 uop on Intel, 2 uops on AMD Zen.  https://godbolt.org/z/5zBx-A.  But without BMI1, [@KevinZ's version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62710316/is-there-an-elegant-and-fast-way-to-test-for-the-1-bits-in-an-integer-to-be-in-a/62724306#62724306) is even more efficient.

Comment: ... _Bool should you not use a standard keyword instead?

Comment: @TommyAndersen: `_Bool` is a standard keyword, per C 2018 6.4.1 1.

Comment: @EricPostpischil then the code is no longer valid c++

Comment: @TommyAndersen There's no requirement it should be valid C++. OP used two language tags but didn't say if the solution must be applicable in _both_ or in _any_ of them. :)

Comment: @TommyAndersen It's fine. Many of the other solutions use C++ only constructs, or compiler-specific intrinsics. Porting it isn't hard.

Comment: @ArminMontigny You mentioned this has been answered several times on SO already – I was of course looking for such answers before posting this question, but couldn't find any (but perhaps I was looking for C++ posts only). Can you please point some out?

Comment: @EricPostpischil How could this be adapted to apply to unsigned integer types?

Comment: @Walter: Hmm? This code uses `unsigned`. If you want to perform the test for a two’s complement signed `int`, the easiest way is to simply pass it to the routine in this answer, letting the `int` be converted to `unsigned`. That will give the desired result. Applying the operations show to a signed `int` directly can be problematic, due to overflow/carry issues. (If you want to test a one’s complement or sign-and-magnitude `int`, that’s another matter, largely only of theoretical interest these days.)

Answer (score 28):

There is actually no need to use any intrinsics.

First flip all the 0s before the first 1. Then test if the new value is a mersenne number. In this algo, zero is mapped to true.

```
bool has_compact_bits( unsigned const x )
{
    // fill up the low order zeroes
    unsigned const y = x | ( x - 1 );
    // test if the 1's is one solid block
    return not ( y & ( y + 1 ) );
}
```

Of course, if you want to use intrinsics, here is the popcount method:

```
bool has_compact_bits( unsigned const x )
{
    size_t const num_bits = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned);
    size_t const sum = __builtin_ctz(x) + __builtin_popcount(x) + __builtin_clz(z);
    return sum == num_bits;
}
```

Comment: First version [reduces to only 4 instructions](https://godbolt.org/z/qahxt3) if compiled with `-mtbm`, exploiting `blsfill`/`blcfill` instructions. It would be the shortest version proposed so far. Unfortunately, [almost no processor support that instruction set extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#TBM_(Trailing_Bit_Manipulation)).

Answer (score 18):

Actually you don't need to count leading zeros. As suggested by pmg in the comments, exploiting the fact that the numbers you are looking for are those of sequence [OEIS A023758](https://oeis.org/A023758), i.e. *Numbers of the form 2^i - 2^j with i >= j*, you may just count trailing zeros (i.e. *j - 1*), toggle those bits in the original value (equivalent to add *2^j - 1*), and then check if that value is of the form *2^i - 1*. With GCC/clang intrinsics,

```
bool has_compact_bits(int val) {
    if (val == 0) return true; // __builtin_ctz undefined if argument is zero
    int j = __builtin_ctz(val) + 1;
    val |= (1 << j) - 1; // add 2^j - 1
    val &= (val + 1); // val set to zero if of the form (2^i - 1)
    return val == 0;
}
```

<s>This version [is slightly faster](https://quick-bench.com/q/CoOvtWYWzk9FxMcqjsXl7YJMDwc) then yours and the one proposed by KamilCuk and the one by Yuri Feldman with popcount only.</s>

If you are using C++20, you may get a portable function by replacing `__builtin_ctz` with [`std::countr_zero`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countr_zero):

```
#include <bit>

bool has_compact_bits(int val) {
    int j = std::countr_zero(static_cast<unsigned>(val)) + 1; // ugly cast
    val |= (1 << j) - 1; // add 2^j - 1
    val &= (val + 1); // val set to zero if of the form (2^i - 1)
    return val == 0;
}
```

The cast is ugly, but it is warning you that it is better to work with unsigned types when manipulating bits. Pre-C++20 alternatives are [`boost::multiprecision::lsb`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/gen_int.html).

**Edit:**

The benchmark on the strikethrough link was limited by the fact that no popcount instruction had been emitted for Yuri Feldman version. Trying to compile them on my PC with `-march=westmere`, I've measured the following time for 1 billion iterations with identical sequences from `std::mt19937`:

- your version: 5.7 s
- KamilCuk's second version: 4.7 s
- my version: 4.7 s
- Eric Postpischil's first version: 4.3 s
- Yuri Feldman's version (using explicitly `__builtin_popcount`): 4.1 s

So, at least on my architecture, the fastest seems to be the one with popcount.

**Edit 2:**

I've updated my benchmark with the new Eric Postpischil's version. As requested in the comments, code of my test can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/YZ94Kb). I've added a no-op loop to estimate the time needed by the PRNG. I've also added the two versions by KevinZ. Code has been compiled on clang with `-O3 -msse4 -mbmi` to get `popcnt` and `blsi` instruction (thanks to Peter Cordes).

Results: At least on my architecture, Eric Postpischil's version is exactly as fast as Yuri Feldman's one, and at least twice faster than any other version proposed so far.

Comment: I removed an operation: `return (x & x + (x & -x)) == 0;`.

Comment: This is benchmarking an older version of @Eric's version, right?  With the current version, Eric's compiles to as few instructions with `gcc -O3 -march=nehalem` (to make popcnt available), or fewer if BMI1 `blsi` is available for `x & -x`: https://godbolt.org/z/zuyj_f.  And the instructions are all simple single-uop, except for the `popcnt` in Yuri's version which has 3 cycle latency.  (But I assume you were benching throughput.)  I also assume you must have removed the `and val` from Yuri's or it would be slower.

Comment: Also, what hardware did you benchmark on?  Linking your full benchmark code on Godbolt or something would be a good idea, so future readers can easily test on their C++ implementation.

Comment: You should also test @KevinZ's version; it compiles to even fewer instructions without BMI1 (at least with clang; gcc's non-inlined version wastes a `mov` and fails to take advantage of `lea`):  https://godbolt.org/z/5jeQLQ.  *With* BMI1, Eric's version is still better on x86-64, at least on Intel where `blsi` is a single uop, but it's 2 uops on AMD.

Answer (score 15):

Not sure about fast, but can do a one-liner by verifying that `val^(val>>1)` has at most 2 bits on.

This only works with unsigned types: shifting in a `0` at the top (logical shift) is necessary, not an arithmetic right shift that shifts in a copy of the sign bit.

```cpp
#include <bitset>
bool has_compact_bits(unsigned val)
{
    return std::bitset<8*sizeof(val)>((val ^ (val>>1))).count() <= 2;
}
```

To reject `0` (i.e. only accept inputs that have exactly 1 contiguous bit-group), logical-AND with `val` being non-zero.  Other answers on this question accept `0` as compact.

```
bool has_compact_bits(unsigned val)
{
    return std::bitset<8*sizeof(val)>((val ^ (val>>1))).count() <= 2 and val;
}
```

C++ portably exposes popcount via `std::bitset::count()`, or [in C++20 via `std::popcount`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount).  C still doesn't have a portable way that reliably compiles to a popcnt or similar instruction on targets where one is available.

Comment: Also the fastest, so far.

Comment: I think you need to use an unsigned type to make sure you shift in zeros, not copies of the sign bit.  Consider `11011111`.  Arithmetic right shifted, it becomes `11101111`, and the XOR is `00110000`.  With logical right shift (shifting in a `0` at the top), you get `10110000` and correctly detect the multiple bit-groups.  Editing to fix that.

Comment: This is really clever. As much as I dislike the style (IMO just use `__builtin_popcount()`, every compiler has a primitive like that nowadays), this is by far the fastest (on a modern cpu). In fact, I am going to argue that that presentation seriously matters, because on a cpu that doesn't have POPCNT as a single instruction, my implementation might beat this. Therefore, if you are going to use this implementation, you should just use the intrinsic. `std::bitset` has a horrible interface.

Answer (score 9):

CPUs have dedicated instructions for that, very fast. On PC they are BSR/BSF (introduced in 80386 in 1985), on ARM they are CLZ/CTZ

Use one to find the index of least significant set bit, shift integer right by that amount. Use another one to find an index of the most significant set bit, compare your integer with (1u<<(bsr+1))-1.

Unfortunately, 35 years wasn't enough to update the C++ language to match the hardware. To use these instructions from C++ you'll need intrinsics, these aren't portable, and return results in slightly different formats. Use preprocessor, `#ifdef` etc, to detect the compiler and then use appropriate intrinsics. In MSVC they are `_BitScanForward`, `_BitScanForward64`, `_BitScanReverse`, `_BitScanReverse64`. In GCC and clang they are `__builtin_clz` and `__builtin_ctz`.

Comment: Maybe you could include some `asm` lines in your answer

Comment: @e2-e4 Visual studio doesn't support inline assembly when compiling for AMD64. That's why I recommend intrinsics.

Comment: Since C++20 there are [`std::countr_zero`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countr_zero) and [`std::countl_zero`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countl_zero). In case you are using Boost, it has portable wrappers called `boost::multiprecision::lsb` and `boost::multiprecision::msb`.

Comment: This does not answer my question at all -- I wonder why it got any upvotes

Comment: @Walter What do you mean “doesn’t answer”? I’ve answered precisely what you should do, use preprocessor and then intrinsics.

Comment: @Walter That’s how authors of libraries, both standard and custom ones, build portable things on top of non-portable ones.

Comment: I think by "portable", the OP meant "_doesn't use machine language instructions unique to certain CPUs_", rather than "_#ifdef though various CPUs and select the appropriate machine language instruction_".

Comment: @Richter65 These particular instructions aren’t unique to certain CPUs. Quite the opposite, they are universally available. This chip http://www.allwinnertech.com/uploads/pdf/2019051511061169.pdf costs less than $2 and yet it’s ARMv7 and therefore has CLZ/CTZ instructions. Even GPUs have these instructions, see firstbithigh and firstbitlow HLSL intrinsics. Just because C++ standardization bodies ain’t supporting something is not a good reason to avoid using it.

Comment: Apparently C++20 finally is adding `#include <bit>` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/bit with bit-scan, popcount, and rotate.  It's pathetic that it took this long to portably expose bit-scan, but now is better than never.  (Portable popcnt has been available through `std::bitset::count()`.)  C++20 is still missing some things that Rust provides (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html), e.g. bit-reverse and endian which *some* CPUs provide efficiently but not all. A portable builtin for an operation that any CPUs have makes some sense, although users need to know what's fast.

Comment: @snoots: "Universally available" is a pretty strong statement, and one I don't think is true.  For example, early MIPS processors didn't have such an instruction.  I'm pretty sure (though not 100% certain) that PowerPC doesn't have one either.

Comment: Also, there's a difference between saying "every CPU has an instruction like that", and "every CPU uses the same instruction", accessible by the same assembly intrinsic.  Even if there first were true (and I don't think it is), the second most certainly is not. So you'd still be left with #ifdef'ing though CPUs.  Even more, to be truly portable, you'd have to guarantee that the intrinsic(s) would apply to all future architectures and all future compilers.  Your suggestion might work on the vast majority of current CPU's, but I think the OP was looking for something truly portable.

Comment: @Richter65 The MIPS instructions are clz/clo, the power instructions are cntlz/cnttzw. Maybe not universally, but available on vast majority of CPUs made this millennium, and even on GPUs made after 2012.

Comment: @Richter65 The second may be true of false depending on compiler. For gcc/clang, you only need to detect the compiler and you don't care about the CPU, these compilers usually do the right CPU-dependent thing with these intrinsic as long as `-march=native`

Answer (score 7):

Comparison with zeros instead of ones will save some operations:

```
bool has_compact_bits2(int val) {
    if (val == 0) return true;
    int h = __builtin_clz(val);
    // Clear bits to the left
    val = (unsigned)val << h;
    int l = __builtin_ctz(val);
    // Invert
    // >>l - Clear bits to the right
    return (~(unsigned)val)>>l == 0;
}
```

The following results in one instructions less then the above on `gcc10 -O3` on x86_64 and uses on sign extension:

```
bool has_compact_bits3(int val) {
    if (val == 0) return true;
    int h = __builtin_clz(val);
    val <<= h;
    int l = __builtin_ctz(val);
    return ~(val>>l) == 0;
}
```

Tested on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GeNViV).

Comment: unfortunately, this is no portable. I'm always afraid I get the operator precendence wrong with those shift operators -- are you sure `~val<<h>>h>>l == 0` does what you think it does?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, edited and added braces anyway. Och, so you are interested in a portable solution? Because I looked at `there exists a faster way?` and assumed anything goes.

Answer (score 5):

You can rephrase the requirement:

- set N the number of bits that are different than the previous one (by iterating through the bits)
- if N=2 and and the first or last bit is 0 then answer is yes
- if N=1 then answer is yes (because all the 1s are on one side)
- if N=0 then and any bit is 0 then you have no 1s, up to you if you consider the answer to be yes or no
- anything else: the answer is no

Going through all bits could look like this:

```
unsigned int count_bit_changes (uint32_t value) {
  unsigned int bit;
  unsigned int changes = 0;
  uint32_t last_bit = value & 1;
  for (bit = 1; bit < 32; bit++) {
    value = value >> 1;
    if (value & 1 != last_bit  {
      changes++;
      last_bit = value & 1;
    }
  }
  return changes;
}
```

But this can surely be optimized (e.g. by aborting the `for` loop when `value` reached `0` which means no more significant bits with value 1 are present).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this sequence of calculations (assuming `val` as an input):

```
uint32_t x = val;
x |= x >>  1;
x |= x >>  2;
x |= x >>  4;
x |= x >>  8;
x |= x >> 16;
```

to obtain a number with all zeros below the most significant `1` filled with ones.

You can also calculate `y = val & -val` to strip all except the least significant 1 bit in `val` (for example, `7 & -7 == 1` and `12 & -12 == 4`).
Warning: this will fail for `val == INT_MIN`, so you'll have to handle this case separately, but this is immediate.

Then right-shift `y` by one position, to get a bit below the actual LSB of `val`, and do the same routine as for `x`:

```
uint32_t y = (val & -val) >> 1;
y |= y >>  1;
y |= y >>  2;
y |= y >>  4;
y |= y >>  8;
y |= y >> 16;
```

Then `x - y` or `x & ~y` or `x ^ y` produces the 'compact' bit mask spanning the whole length of `val`. Just compare it to `val` to see if `val` is 'compact'.

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of the [gcc builtin instructions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) to check if:

**The count of set bits**

> int __builtin_popcount (unsigned int x)
> Returns the number of 1-bits in x.

is equal to (a - b):

**a**: Index of the highest set bit (32 - CTZ) (32 because 32 bits in an unsigned integer).

> int __builtin_clz (unsigned int x)
> Returns the number of leading 0-bits in x, starting at the most significant bit position. If x is 0, the result is undefined.

**b**: Index of the lowest set bit (CLZ):

> int __builtin_clz (unsigned int x)
> Returns the number of leading 0-bits in x, starting at the most significant bit position. If x is 0, the result is undefined.

For example if n = 0b0001100110; we will obtain 4 with popcount but the index difference (a - b) will return 6.

```c
bool has_contiguous_one_bits(unsigned n) {
    return (32 - __builtin_clz(n) - __builtin_ctz(n)) == __builtin_popcount(n);
}
```

which can also be written as:

```c
bool has_contiguous_one_bits(unsigned n) {
    return (__builtin_popcount(n) + __builtin_clz(n) + __builtin_ctz(n)) == 32;
}
```

I don't think it is more elegant or efficient than the current most upvoted answer:

```c
return (x & x + (x & -x)) == 0;
```

with following assembly:

```
mov     eax, edi
neg     eax
and     eax, edi
add     eax, edi
test    eax, edi
sete    al
```

but it is probably easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is a version that loops over bits

```
template<typename Integer>
inline constexpr bool has_compact_bits(Integer val) noexcept
{
    Integer test = 1;
    while(!(test & val) && test) test<<=1; // skip unset bits to find first set bit
    while( (test & val) && test) test<<=1; // skip set bits to find next unset bit
    while(!(test & val) && test) test<<=1; // skip unset bits to find an offending set bit
    return !test;
}
```

The first two loops found the first compact region. The final loop checks whether there is any other set bit beyond that region.