# Invert operation for bitwise in C

Tags: c, bit-shift

Dear all C programmer:

`X = 1 << N;      (left shift)`

how to recover N from X ?

Thanks

Comment: Do it on paper: Right shift until you get `1`. Then the number of shifts in `N`. Very simple programming task.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a while loop, keep shifting right until X==1, record how many times you have to shift right and the counter will give you N.

```
int var = X;
int count = 0;
while (var != 1){
    var >>= 1; 
    count++;
}
printf("N is %d", count);
```

Comment: This is problematic when X `var` is negative or when `X` has the type `unsigned` and the highest bit is set. Better use `unsigned` for var. Even better would be `uintmax_t` since it could be that `sizeof X>=sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: If `X` is negative, then the shift in `X = 1 << N;` overflowed, and none of the answers work because the behavior of the program is not defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 2):

`N` in this case is the bit position where you shifted in a `1` at. Assuming that `X` here only got one bit set. Then to find out what number that bit position corresponds to, you have to iterate through the data and mask with bitwise AND:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(X)*8; i++)
  if(X & (1<<i))
    printf("%d", i);
```

If performance is important, then you'd make a look-up table with all possible results instead.

Comment: If `sizeof X>sizeof(int) && sizeof X >sizeof(size_t)` you get UB even when you add a -1. In this case you would need a cast to the type of X first.

Comment: `8` assumes that `CHAR_BIT==8`, which can be false. Why not use `CHAR_BIT` directly? And `1<<(sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT)` can be UB when `sizeof(int)=>sizeof(size_t)`, i think you forgot a `-1`.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Because I'm not interested in providing portability to extremely exotic, fictional or otherwise dysfunctional systems. The only real-world computers I know that actually have other char sizes are various obsolete TI DSPs and if someone decides to program those in C while at the same time aimlessly importing random standard C libs found on the internet, then that incompetence is their problem, not mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([flsl from here](http://web.mit.edu/freebsd/head/sys/libkern/flsl.c) which is available from string.h on macOS) :

```
int flsl(long mask)
{
    int bit;

    if (mask == 0) return (0);
    for (bit = 1; mask != 1; bit++)
        mask = (unsigned long)mask >> 1;
    return (bit);
}

unsigned char binlog(long mask) { return mask ? flsl(mask) - 1 : 0; }

int x = 1 << 20;
printf("%d\n", binlog(x)); ===> 20
```