# How to efficiently extract the bit position as a value in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, c-preprocessor

I'm looking for an efficient (preferably macro) way to extract the position of a bit and save it as a value in C.

```
data = 0x4000
```

would produce:

```
pos = 14
```

There is only going to be one bit set in the 16-bit register I'm reading. Currently, I'm just comparing the data to bit shifted values to extract the position, but there's gotta be a better way I don't know about.

I spent some time searching through here for a similar question and couldn't find one.

Comment: It's a 16-bit value? Write a `switch` statement that identifies which of the 16 bits is set.

Comment: Either you go for a Switch Case, or you go for a loop with a mask `(data & (1<<n))`

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?  It seems like you're trying to put a square peg in a round hole here (xy problem)

Comment: Are you targeting a specific compiler?  If so, there may be a built-in function you can use.

Comment: What would be your expected result if i.E. data = 0x807f?

Comment: @Devolus *There is only going to be one bit set in the 16-bit register*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i

Comment: not trying to fit a square peg in a round hole here... I have a vendor giving me a device that has a 16-bit register that has 1 bit (and only 1) set at a time. that bit corresponds to a "database" of values in other registers in their device as the index. so if bit 14 is set, I need to go read that 14th entry's set of registers.

Comment: @dbush gcc version 8.2.0 for an ARM Cortex-R5... I'll look into hacatu's comment as well.

Comment: From what I can tell, ARM processors have at least count leading zeros so any of the similar bit scan builtins should compile to one or two instructions

Comment: For questions like this, I usually consult this: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern processors have single instructions to do this (count trailing zeros, find first set, count leading zeros, and find last set).  In gcc and clang, `__builtin_ctz(n)` will return the number of trailing zeros in a number.  On processors where single instruction ctz is supported, it compiles to one instruction.  Make sure to use a sufficiently wide function (ie `__builtin_ctz` for `int` or narrower, `__builtin_ctzl` for `long int` or narrower, or `__builtin_ctzll` for `long long int` or narrower.  For a 16 bit register, `__builtin_ctz` should be sufficient.

See [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set) for more information.

Comment: This is exactly why I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A platform agnostic solution is the most portable and valid one, but it's also pessimistic; a lot of modern processors have instructions and intrinsics for bit operations like this.

For example, x86-64 have the `bsf` instruction which will populate one operand with the location of the most significant set bit in the other operand:

```
bsf eax, 0x00004000
; eax now holds the value '14'
```

However, a 'pure' C solution would look something like:

```
int MSBPos = 0;
while(data && !(data & 1)) // 'data' check avoids infinite loop if data is 0
{
    MSBPos++;
    data >>= 1;
}
```

Note, this only works in OP's case where he's guaranteed that there is a single set bit in the entire value and all other bits are 0.

I wouldn't worry about it being a linear algorithm though; bit operations are incredibly fast.

Comment: up-voted for a good answer.  the __builtin_ctzl() was easy to use and accomplished the task in 3 instructions. 2 moves and the bsf you noted. as a point of comparison, I generated the assembly for your while loop too. It accomplishes the task in pure C as you stated in just +6 instructions and a couple jumps. In my case, I'll leverage the built-in, but for a more portable solution, the while loop is efficient as well. thanks!