# what is the most efficient way to flip all the bits from the least significant bit up to the most significant last 1 bit value?

Tags: c, x86, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, bitmask

Say for example I have a `uint8_t` that can be of any value, and I only want to flip all the bits from the least significant bit up to the most significant last 1 bit value? How would I do that in the most efficient way?, Is there a solution where I can avoid using a loop?

here are some cases:

left side is the original bits - right side after the flips.

- `00011101` -> `00000010`
- `00000000` -> `00000000`
- `11111111` -> `00000000`
- `11110111` -> `00001000`
- `01000000` -> `00111111`

**[EDIT]**

The type could also be larger than `uint8_t`, It could be `uint32_t`, `uint64_t` and `__uint128_t`. I just use `uint8_t` because it's the easiest size to show in the example cases.

Comment: Define "efficient". What measure? `uint8_t` is only 256 values so you could have a lookup table.

Comment: I just use ```uint8_t``` as an example because it's the easiest to represent but the number could also be ```uint32_t```, ```uint64_t``` and even ```__uint128_t```

Comment: Architecture-specific or portable solution ?

Comment: @PaulR for now I'm currently working on an x86_64 so maybe x86_64.

Comment: If you have a quick way to [count leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673781/3386109), the rest is easy.

Comment: @user3386109 yes but the simple solution of `x ^ (ones >> lzcnt(x))` doesn't work (dies if `x = 0`) so there is something interesting about the rest as well

Comment: @harold The `x == 0` case can be handled with a conditional operator `return (x==0) ? 0 : (ones >> lzcnt(x));` which gcc can compile to a conditional move on x86.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general I expect that most solutions will have roughly this form:

1. Compute the mask of bits that need to flipped
2. XOR by that mask

As mentioned in the comments, x64 is a target of interest, and on x64 you can do step 1 like this:

- Find the 1-based position `p` of the most significant 1, by leading zeroes (`_lzcnt_u64`) and subtracting that from 64 (or 32 whichever is appropriate).
- Create a mask with `p` consecutive set bits starting from the least significant bit, probably using `_bzhi_u64`.

There are some variations, such as using BitScanReverse to find the most significant 1 (but it has an ugly case for zero), or using a shift instead of `bzhi` (but it has an ugly case for 64). `lzcnt` and `bzhi` is a good combination with no ugly cases. `bzhi` requires BMI2 (Intel Haswell or newer, AMD Zen or newer).

Putting it together:

```
x ^ _bzhi_u64(~(uint64_t)0, 64 - _lzcnt_u64(x))
```

**Which could be further simplified to**

```
_bzhi_u64(~x,  64 - _lzcnt_u64(x))
```

As shown by Peter. This doesn't follow the original 2-step plan, rather *all* bits are flipped, and then the bits that were originally leading zeroes are reset.

Since those original leading zeroes form a contiguous sequence of leading ones in `~x`, an alternative to `bzhi` could be to add the appropriate power of two to `~x` (though sometimes zero, which might be thought of as 2<sup>64</sup>, putting the set bit just beyond the top of the number). Unfortunately the power of two that we need is a bit annoying to compute, at least I could not come up with a good way to do it, it seems like a dead end to me.

Step 1 could also be implemented in a generic way (no special operations) using a few shifts and bitwise ORs, like this:

```
// Get all-ones below the leading 1
// On x86-64, this is probably slower than Paul R's method using BSR and shift
//   even though you have to special case x==0
m = x | (x >> 1);
m |= m >> 2;
m |= m >> 4;
m |= m >> 8;
m |= m >> 16;
m |= m >> 32;  // last step should be removed if x is 32-bit
```

AMD CPUs have slowish BSR (but fast LZCNT; https://uops.info/), so you might want this shift/or version for `uint8_t` or `uint16_t` (where it takes fewest steps), especially if you need compatibility with all CPUs *and* speed on AMD is more important than on Intel.

This generic version is also useful within SIMD elements, especially narrow ones, where we don't have a leading-zero-count until AVX-512.

Comment: It seems that I don't have the ```_bzhi_u64``` instruction, though the alternative you provided worked.

Comment: @kabibesadagat you probably shouldn't use that "generic" way unless you really have to (6 of those shift-OR steps isn't great, not horrible either, but not great), you can still use a shift to replace the BZHI as long as you deal with the edge case

Comment: @kabibesadagat: You never need the "generic" version of the `m = x | (x>>1)` stuff on an x86 CPU.  You always have at least `__builtin_clzll` or equivalent, which can at worst compile to a BSR instruction, so you need to special-case zero.  Or in 32-bit mode, two BSR instructions on the halves, and other checks.  But anyway, the `bzhi` part is what needs replacing if you don't have it, not the `lzcnt` part.

Comment: @harold: `_bzhi_u64(~x,  64 - _lzcnt_u64(x))` avoids needing a constant `-1`, saving an instruction or two depending on compiler.  https://godbolt.org/z/edqMf5GMa  **The not-flipped bits are all zero.**

Answer (score 4):

TL:DR: use a `uint64_t` shift to implement efficiently with `uint32_t` when compiling for 64-bit machines that have `lzcnt` (AMD since K10, Intel since Haswell).  Without `lzcnt` (only `bsr` that's baseline for x86) the `n==0` case is still special.

---

For the `uint64_t` version, the hard part is that you have 65 different possible positions for the highest set bit, including non-existent (`lzcnt` producing 64 when all bits are zero).  But a single shift with 64-bit operand-size on x86 can only produce one of 64 different values (assuming a constant input), since x86 shifts mask the count like `foo >> (c&63)`

Using a shift requires special-casing one leading-bit-position, typically the `n==0` case.  As Harold's answer shows, [BMI2 `bzhi`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bzhi) avoids that, allowing bit counts from 0..64.

Same for 32-bit operand-size shifts: they mask `c&31`.  **But to generate a mask for `uint32_t`, we can use a 64-bit shift efficiently on x86-64.**  (Or 32-bit for uint16_t and uint8_t.  Fun fact: x86 asm shifts with 8 or 16-bit operand-size still mask their count mod 32, so they can shift out all the bits without even using a wider operand-size.  But 32-bit operand size is efficient, no need to mess with partial-register writes.)

This strategy is even more efficient than bzhi for a type narrower than register width.

```
// optimized for 64-bit mode, otherwise 32-bit bzhi or a cmov version of Paul R's is good

#ifdef __LZCNT__
#include <immintrin.h>
uint32_t flip_32_on_64(uint32_t n)
{
    uint64_t mask32 = 0xffffffff;  // (uint64_t)(uint32_t)-1u32
    // this needs to be _lzcnt_u32, not __builtin_clz; we need 32 for n==0
    // If lznct isn't available, we can't avoid handling n==0  zero specially
    uint32_t mask = mask32 >> _lzcnt_u32(n);
    return n ^ mask;
}
#endif
```

**This works equivalently for `uint8_t` and `uint16_t`** (literally the same code with same mask, using a 32-bit lzcnt on them after zero-extension).  **But *not* `uint64_t`** (You could use a `unsigned __int128` shift, but `shrd` masks its shift count mod 64 so compilers still need some conditional behaviour to emulate it.  So you might as well do a manual cmov or something, or `sbb same,same` to generate a `0` or `-1` in a register as the mask to be shifted.)

**[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AB9U8lJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYMQkgGykHAGTwGTAA5dwAjTGIvAFZSAAdUBUJbBmc3Dy9fROSbAUDgsJZI6Mk4y0xrVKECJmICdPdPHwtMKzyGGrqCAtCIqNiLWvrGzJaFYZ6gvuKBsoBKC1RXYmR2DgBSACYAZiDkNywAag2dxwn8QQA6BFPsDY0AQQfH1yCCHa3jAiOqWjx4hA3oJPt8jgx5i8NgB2ABCLyOiKOeCoRwgDBOOwAIqcsUcNPMjsRMAQVhiNKd4U8EUjgR8vj8WEwFABrTF4gB%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%2BUwPU9uE20KFRVAEDx4TEkwLJBMAw1HM1jDIqi21oCw8R0FVFH%2BclBBXIuyoZj6q55uuMJFtsOwOCiW7PDuqJHcE6AQKYsIALIqV8xiEts3h80cTP0azxiqAAHN4AGSKYTqvFB0vGv8FbOR1tAszhCtHKosswhBSrphiqhqol4SSlRnGARAHLAbh8waDxgFHD2rGSuxBAW0B2sLoWdMa9%2BSvRmbeA25r2vNoTBuCqb5uuJbHKqA7khOy7bsexAXvk5u%2Br09Th0ohwiy0JwMS8J4HBaKQqCcKtCjLKs4lUzwpAEJoBeLCyIA7DsVwxFwACcYsaGLkilZIfc%2BNxRccJIvAsBIGj22XFdVxwvAKCA9st%2BXBekHAsBIOjmP0GQFAQIfWPRMgJVcDsfCxlE68QOErekMDzDEGFnBN%2BjbCCAA8gwcKL8sBMiMOIbepB8DEiqJtF%2BmBVCVFcAQdYTd3htBfv8KGdQwrOCwC/Agr457cB3n8JgwAFAADU8CYBEn/IKZcm78EECIMQ7ApAyEEIoFQ6gIG6C4PoYqIBTASn0HgcI69ICLE%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%2BG8FsXufctiSDFtCUZUzp6uogcsiwqz2lt0LVsYty9OBtPWYsFqxBkh2EkEAA)** with gcc and clang.  Note that it's not safe to replace `_lzcnt_u32` with `__builtin_clz`; clang11 and later assume that can't produce 32 even when they compile it to an `lzcnt` instruction<sup>1</sup>, and optimize the shift operand-size down to 32 which will act as `mask32 >> clz(n) & 31`.

```
# clang 14 -O3 -march=haswell  (or znver1 or bdver4 or other BMI2 CPUs)
flip_32_on_64:
        lzcnt   eax, edi           # skylake fixed the output false-dependency for lzcnt/tzcnt, but not popcnt.  Clang doesn't care, it's reckless about false deps except inside a loop in a single function.
        mov     ecx, 4294967295
        shrx    rax, rcx, rax
        xor     eax, edi
        ret
```

Without BMI2, e.g. with `-march=bdver1` or `barcelona` (aka k10), we get the same code-gen except with `shr rax, cl`.  Those CPUs do still have `lzcnt`, otherwise this wouldn't compile.

(I'm curious if Intel Skylake Pentium/Celeron run `lzcnt` as `lzcnt` or `bsf`.  They lack BMI1/BMI2, but `lzcnt` has its own feature flag.
It seems low-power uarches as recent as Tremont are missing `lzcnt`, though, according to [InstLatx64 for a Pentium Silver N6005 Jasper Lake-D, Tremont core](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel/GenuineIntel00906C0_JasperLake_01_InstLatX64.txt).  I didn't manually look for the feature bit in the raw CPUID dumps of recent Pentium/Celeron, but [Instlat](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/) does have those available if someone wants to check.)

Anyway, `bzhi` also requires BMI2, so if you're comparing against that for any size but `uint64_t`, this is the comparison.

This `shrx` version can keep its `-1` constant around in a register across loops.  So the `mov reg,-1` can be hoisted out of a loop after inlining, if the compiler has a spare register.  The best `bzhi` strategy doesn't need a mask constant so it has nothing to gain.    `_bzhi_u64(~x, 64 - _lzcnt_u64(x))` is 5 uops, but works for 64-bit integers on 64-bit machines.  Its latency critical path length is the same as this.  (lzcnt / sub / bzhi).

---

Without LZCNT, one option might be to always flip as a way to get FLAGS set for CMOV, and use `-1 << bsr(n)` to XOR some of them back to the original state.  This could reduce critical path latency.  IDK if a C compiler could be coaxed into emitting this.  Especially not if you want to take advantage of the fact that real CPUs keep the BSR destination unchanged if the source was zero, but only AMD documents this fact.  (Intel says it's an "undefined" result.)

(TODO: finish this hand-written asm idea.)

---

Other C ideas for the `uint64_t` case: `cmov` or `cmp/sbb` (to generate a `0` or `-1`) in parallel with `lzcnt` to shorten the critical path latency?  See the Godbolt link where I was playing with that.

ARM/AArch64 saturate their shift counts, unlike how x86 masks for scalar.  If one could take advantage of that safely (without C shift-count UB) that would be neat, allowing something about as good as this.

x86 *SIMD* shifts also saturate their counts, which Paul R took advantage of with an AVX-512 answer using `vlzcnt` and variable-shift.  (It's not worth copying data to an XMM reg and back for one scalar shift, though; only useful if you have multiple elements to do.)

#### Footnote 1: clang codegen with `__builtin_clz` or `...ll`

Using `__builtin_clzll(n)` will get clang to use 64-bit operand-size for the shift, since values from 32 to 63 become possible.  But you can't actually use that to compile for CPUs without `lzcnt`.  The 63-`bsr` a compiler would use without lzcnt available would not produce the `64` we need for that case.  Not unless you did `n<<=1;` / `n|=1;` or something before the `bsr` and adjusted the result, but that would be slower than `cmov`.

If you were using a 64-bit `lzcnt`, you'd want `uint64_t mask = -1ULL` since there will be 32 extra leading zeros after zero-extending to `uint64_t`.  Fortunately all-ones is relatively cheap to materialize on all ISAs, so use that instead of `0xffffffff00000000ULL`

Comment: Isn't that weird thing Clang 11+ does with a 32-bit shift a consequence of `__builtin_clz` being undefined for zero, so it thinks that 32 is not a possible shift count? It goes away if I use `_lzcnt_u64` or `__builtin_clzll` there

Comment: @harold: ah, that would be it.  Yeah, coming back to this today I realized that it needed to be `lzcnt` not `__builtin_clz` which could use `bsr`, but hadn't updated the Godbolt link, and hadn't thought through the implications for the clang code-gen.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a simple example for 32 bit ints that works with gcc and compatible compilers (clang *et al*), and is portable across most architectures.

```
uint32_t flip(uint32_t n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    uint32_t mask = ~0U >> __builtin_clz(n);
    return n ^ mask;
}
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](https://www.ideone.com/2zg1b3)

We could avoid the extra check for n==0 if we used `lzcnt` on x86-64 (or `clz` on ARM), *and* we were using a shift that allowed a count of 32.  (In C, shifts by the type-width or larger are undefined behaviour.  On x86, in practice the shift count is masked `&31` for shifts other than 64-bit, so this could be usable for `uint16_t` or `uint8_t` using a `uint32_t` mask.)

Be careful to avoid C undefined behaviour, including any assumption about `__builtin_clz` with an input of 0; modern C compilers are not portable assemblers, even though we sometimes wish they were when the language doesn't portably expose the CPU features we want to take advantage of.  For example, clang assumes that `__builtin_clz(n)` can't be 32 even when it compiles it to `lzcnt`.

See [@PeterCordes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72008764/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-flip-all-the-bits-from-the-least-significant-b/72029567#72029567) for details.

Comment: I wonder if this will be faster by a large margin than @harold's alternative solution for ```uint32_t```?

Comment: Very similar to Harold’s BMI solution, I would expect. The one advantage of the above is that it’s portable across most/all architectures, since the compiler will use the most efficient instruction sequence available for `__builtin_clz` on the target platform.

Comment: This makes sense, and could be made branchless by doing `mask = (n == 0 ? 0 : mask);` after the `-1U >> clz`.  For 64-bit, use `__builtin_clzll`.  With BMI2 for efficient shifts, it can compile even more efficiently.

Comment: If you're only doing 32-bit ints on a 64-bit machine, you can use `0xffffffffULL >> _lzcnt_u32(n)` so it can shift out all the bits if the leading-zero count is 32.  (Instead of masking the shift-count to 0 for a 32-bit shift on x86 / x86-64.)  ARM / AArch64 saturate shift counts, so if there's a way in C to express that, we could conceivably get `clz` and shift to do the trick without a zero check for full-width registers.

Comment: Don't *just* use `-mlzcnt`!  Use `-march=haswell` to enable BMI1 and BMI2 as well, for efficient variable-count shifts on Intel, and not needing to use CL for the count.  (AMD K10 and later have lzcnt, but only Zen for BMI2. Also excludes pentium/celeron pre Icelake).  https://godbolt.org/z/Ej4GYxxec .  Hrm, looks like a clang code-gen bug in clang 11 and later, using only 32-bit operand-size for my `(uint64_t)-1u32 >> clz` idea.  But when compiled correctly, it's only 4 instructions plus a ret.  (Or 5 if tuning properly for Haswell not Skylake, breaking the output dependency of `lzcnt`.)

Comment: This is still pretty good with just `-mlzcnt`, though, perhaps comparable to Harold's which also requires BMI2 for `bzhi`.  Actually for uint32_t on x86-64, 64-bit shift operand-size seems even better.  https://godbolt.org/z/Y51x15x85

Comment: (writing this up into an answer myself, BTW.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I'd been oblivious to lzcnt v bsr etc previously, so it's been interesting to catch up on this. I look forward to your (no doubt comprehensive!) answer in due course.

Comment: Unfortunately you introduced a bug here: `~0U >> 32` is UB, and on x86 will work like `~0U >> 0`.  Using `((uint64_t)~0U) >> lzcnt`  is safe, but not with `__builtin_clz`.  clang11 and later know that clz(n) produces an undefined result for n==0, and use that to assume that the count can never be 32.  (Even if it ends up compiling to an `lzcnt` instruction, unfortunately).  I'm just going to basically roll that back in your answer, since I did end up posting an answer myself.

Comment: @PeterCordes: thanks for catching that - I was just trying to save a potentially redundant CMOV when using lzcnt, and of course I messed up.

Answer (score 2):

If your use case is performance-critical you might also want to consider a SIMD implementation for performing the bit flipping operation on a large number of elements. Here's an example using AVX512 for 32 bit elements:

```
void flip(const uint32_t in[], uint32_t out[], size_t n)
{
    assert((n & 7) == 0); // for this example we only handle arrays which are vector multiples in size
    for (size_t i = 0; i + 8 <= n; i += 8)
    {
        __m512i vin = _mm512_loadu_si512(&in[i]);
        __m512i vlz = _mm512_lzcnt_epi32(vin);
        __m512i vmask = _mm512_srlv_epi32(_mm512_set1_epi32(-1), vlz);
        __m512i vout = _mm512_xor_si512(vin, vmask);
        _mm512_storeu_si512(&out[i], vout);
    }
}
```

This uses the same approach as other solutions, i.e. count leading zeroes, create mask, XOR, but for 32 bit elements it processes 8 elements per loop iteration. You could implement a 64 bit version of this similarly, but unfortunately there are no similar AVX512 intrinsics for element sizes < 32 bits or > 64 bits.

You can see the above 32 bit example in action on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/81YdvY4eK) (note: you might need to hit the refresh button at the bottom of the assembly pane to get it to re-compile and run if you get "Program returned: 139" in the output pane - this seems to be due to a glitch in Compiler Explorer currently).

Comment: Oh nice, good one since x86 SIMD shifts saturate their count (so they can shift out all the bits), unlike scalar shifts which mask it so it wraps around.  (And unlike ISO C shifts where `uint32_t >> 32` is simply undefined behaviour.)